# Custom dialogue box cannot be closed

Tags: android

Here is my code for an activity that embeds in itself a custom dialog box:

```
package com.example.hotel_app_regularuser;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.TypedValue;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GetUserPreference extends Activity implements Runnable {
    TextView tv,tr;
    Button bt;
    Thread t1;
    Dialog d;
    ObjectAnimator textColorAnim;
    LinearLayout lyt,lyt2; 
    PopupWindow popUp;
    LayoutParams params;
    Button cbutton;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_user_preference);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        lyt= (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
        lyt2=new LinearLayout(this);
        popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
        t1=new Thread(this);
        cbutton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
        Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/rs.ttf"); 
        Intent it=getIntent();
        String a=it.getStringExtra("username");
        tv.setText("Welcome"+"   "+a);
        tv.setTypeface(type);
        tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,50);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        d = new Dialog(this);
        bt=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
        animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second
        animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
        animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation infinitely
        animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in
        // bt.startAnimation(animation);
        bt.startAnimation(animation);
        d.setContentView(R.layout.customxml);
        d.setTitle("welcome");
        TextView t = (TextView)d.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        t.setText("hiii");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.get_user_preference, menu);
        return true;
    }


    public void go(View vw)
    {
        d.show();   
    }

    public void rempopup(View v)
    {
        d.dismiss();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){}
}
```

**Here is my customxml.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/closebutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:onClick="rempopup"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Problem is, when i click on the button in the custom dialogue box, my app closes abruptly. The dismiss() isn't called for some reason. Please help

**Here is my crash log**

```
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455): Process: com.example.hotel_app_regularuser, PID: 19455
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method rempopup(View) in the activity class android.view.ContextThemeWrapper for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'closebutton'
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4034)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4802)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20101)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:810)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:189)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5532)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: rempopup [class android.view.View]
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:664)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:643)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4027)
07-04 10:57:29.340: E/AndroidRuntime(19455):    ... 10 more
```

Comment: Please post your crash log.

Comment: how you are calling this method `rempopup()`

Comment: tried using xml.. but it didnt work out..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class GetUserPreference extends Activity implements Runnable {
        TextView tv, tr;
        Button bt;
        Thread t1;
        Dialog d;
        ObjectAnimator textColorAnim;
        LinearLayout lyt, lyt2;
        PopupWindow popUp;
        LayoutParams params;
        Button cbutton;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_user_preference);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            lyt = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LinearLayout1);
            lyt2 = new LinearLayout(this);
            popUp = new PopupWindow(this);
            t1 = new Thread(this);
            cbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
            Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/rs.ttf");
            Intent it = getIntent();
            String a = it.getStringExtra("username");
            tv.setText("Welcome" + "   " + a);
            tv.setTypeface(type);
            tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 50);
            tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
            d = new Dialog(this);
            bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            final Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0); // Change alpha from fully visible to invisible
            animation.setDuration(500); // duration - half a second
            animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator()); // do not alter animation rate
            animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); // Repeat animation infinitely
            animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.REVERSE); // Reverse animation at the end so the button will fade back in
            // bt.startAnimation(animation);
            bt.startAnimation(animation);
            d.setContentView(R.layout.customxml);
            d.setTitle("welcome");
            TextView t = (TextView) d.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            t.setText("hiii");
            Button close_btn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.closebutton);
            close_btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    d.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.get_user_preference, menu);
            return true;
        }


        public void go(View vw) {
            d.show();
        }

//        public void rempopup(View v) {
//            d.dismiss();
//        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
        }
    }
```

also remove

`android:onClick="rempopup"`

Comment: if still have some issue comment here.

Comment: Great! It worked like a charm! Thanx. But the only change i saw u made was placing onClickListener at the end..Does it make a difference?

Comment: no problem of placing it just add after creating dialog.

Comment: Sorry i just saw what changes u made...Thanx so much! Button close_btn = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.closebutton);

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Edited**

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
Button Button = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.closebutton);

Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   d.dismiss();
  }
});
```

And in your .xml file

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/closebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"/>
```

Hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void rempopup(View v)
    {
     if(v.getId() == R.id.closebutton)
               d.dismiss();
    }
```